# Debugging incorrect certificate with SNI for some clients

Tags: ssl, haproxy, sni

I have a number of domains with SSL certificates served by Haproxy (using Haproxy 1.5's support for SSL). For the most part the correct certificates are being served, but a particular user is incorrectly receiving the default certificate. The strange thing is that they are using Chrome 22 on Windows 7, which most definitely does support SNI.

Does anyone have any tips as to how I can go about diagnosing what is causing this, whether server configuration or client weirdness.

Comment: Have him go to a [SNI test site](https://sni.velox.ch/) and report to you the results. (Also make sure they are going to the correct URL!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Why is this not an answer?